# Calculating fourier series to get the sum of a sequence

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The problems says:
By doing an ODD extraction of the function: $$f(x)=\frac{x-\pi}{2}, x \in (0,\pi)$$
calculate the following series:
$$   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$$

My main problem is that in the exam (2 weeks from now) I've got 30 questions and I suppose that I have to calculate $b_n$ (since it is odd) and after that I should use Parseval's, right?

After calculating $b_n$ I get this (symbolab calculator):

[image]

It really takes a long time just to get to the result, but what do I do now with it?

Here are the results if that helps: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \tag{1}$$
is the Fourier series of a sawtooth wave. Over the interval $(0,\pi)$ we have $g(x)=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$,
hence by evaluating both sides of $(1)$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ it follows that

$$ \frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}\tag{2} $$

Comment: Sir, Hod did your first g(x) formula come up? How did you get it? Do I have to calculate bn?

Comment: I haven't the slighest clue about what **bn** is, but you may derive $(1)$ by computing the Fourier sine series of a $\pi$-periodic function that equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ over $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: @wesewx To do that, compute, by integration by parts, the value of $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}\sin(nx)\,dx.$$

Comment: May I ask you Sir, how long would it take you to integrate the above function? Of course without any calculators?

Comment: @wesewx: depending on your expertise, from 2 seconds to a couple of minutes. What is the derivative of $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$? What is a primitive of $\sin(nx)$? Pretty simple through integration by parts.

Comment: Okay, I've got, It's hard to follow your sometimes, you are just too brilliant, enjoying learning on this site!